# generating coverity connect authentication key

Tags: authentication, key, coverity

I have installed coverity connect/platform on a server. To connect to it via coverity analysis, it prompts me to input authentication keys. How do i generate auth keys for coverity connect?

Answer (score 1):

Did you try something like:

```
$ cov-manage-im --host your_host --port 8080 --user USERNAME \
    --password YOURPWD --mode auth-key --create --output-file ~/auth.file
```